# Swagger POST body list

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I've been searching fruitlessly on how to swagger spec a POST body with a list inside of it. How do I do it? Here's what I have:

```
/groups:
    post:
      summary: Creates a group
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          schema:
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              description:
                type: string
              groupType:
                type: string
                enum: [ "open", "closed", "secret" ]
              users:
                type: string list # <--------- a list of strings
      responses:
        201:
          description: Group created
        default:
          description: Group creation failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For property being an array of string, please refer to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L660 as an example:

```
  photoUrls:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```